# os.system call not working?

Tags: python, database

I am using the following code to call two different scripts:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
title=soup.find('title')
os.system("python scraper/updatedb.py %s" % (title))
os.system("python scraper/insertlinks.py %s" % (tag['href']))
```

The second one is running but the first one is not running. Please help.
`updatedb.py` and `insertlinks.py` work fine when run individually.

`updatedb.py` is as follows:

```
import sqlite3 as db
import sys
print "inserted"
key=sys.argv[1]
id="1"
conn=db.connect('store.db')
cursor=conn.cursor()
with conn:
    cursor.execute('insert into records (id,keyword) values(?,?)',(id,key))
conn.close()
```

Comment: Whenever I use os.system, I use assert like this:
assert os.system("python scraper/updatedb.py %s" % (title)) == 0, "os.system call falied"

Without knowing the contents of updatedb.py and the value of title, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @SaqibAli I added updatedb.py

Comment: Think about it for a second - what if `title` was `foo;rm -fr *` ?

Comment: the problem is with the `os.system` call. The command prompt says `The syntax of the command is incorrect`

Comment: BTW, `os.system` is deprecated. You should use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os.system always returns the code, `error code` if not executed the command and `0` if it is executed successfully.

```
result_code = os.system("your command")
```

you can check the error message on google by using python error code

Comment: I am getting `1` for every single call. The link you suggested says `Memory allocation failure`. I have no idea what to do?